# Setting up a source using ID and limiting the items you can select. is it possible?

Tags: templates

I'm building a template and I want to limit the items the authors can select on a TreeListEx field. I know this can be done specifying the datasource as posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24952880/sitecore-restrict-item-by-data-template-type-on-a-field)

Like setting the value on the Source field:

`DataSource=/sitecore/content/home/foo&ExcludeTemplatesForSelection=Bar`

This is fine, although you are hard coding a path which might not be desired if the ability to move items is desidered.

What if I'm setting an ID on the source field like shown here? How can I limit the selection?

[image]

Comment: I might be missing something, but is there a reason why you can't use the `StartSearchLocation` syntax and apply a filter on top of that? That way you would still be able to specify the ID of where to look, then apply the additional filtering?

Comment: As far as I know StartSearchLocation is used for these types: 
Multilist with Search
Treelist with Search
Query Builder
Query Datasource

TreeListEX I don't think there is that option

Comment: Right, my mistake.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the ID instead of the path in your initial source:

```
DataSource={C46A-4...CE}&ExcludeTemplatesForSelection=Bar
```

Comment: Hum I tried using the ID and changing the name for the template name on the ExcludeTemplatesForSelection but still I can add the value. I tried to set the template with it's id as well but still I can select it like this:

DataSource={F1AF7A72-C46A-4FC2-BF3B-7325A4DDB0CE}&ExcludeTemplatesForSelection={19BEA9FA-08C7-4D8F-B1B8-08CA5D288B87}

Comment: You can use the ID in the datasource, but not on the ExcludeTemplates..

Comment: thanks Gatogordo. that's useful. IT worked like this:
DataSource={F1AF7A72-C46A-4FC2-BF3B-7325A4DDB0CE}&ExcludeTemplatesForSelection=MyTemplateName